# Download a webpage and remove HTML code from the downloaded webpage

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to download a whole webpage, text and images. For example I have a URL and I apply the `dowload.file` function.

```
URL = "https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/vivienda/barcelona-capital/aire-acondicionado-calefaccion-ascensor/164412189/d?from=list"

download.file(url = URL, destfile = "/home/myFolder/tst.html")
```

However, I don't see the images downloaded. I have 2 questions.

a) How can I download the images into a folder?
b) How can I remove the terms and conditions "accept and close" box?

Since I download the HTML code, could I just remove this part in the original HTML code?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is how you download the pictures into a folder

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

"https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/vivienda/barcelona-capital/aire-acondicionado-calefaccion-ascensor/164412189/d?from=list" %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_elements(".re-DetailMosaicPhoto") %>%  
  html_attr("src") %>%  
  imap(., ~ download.file(url = .x, 
                          destfile = paste0(.y, ".jpg")))
```